# Scalability of Web Content Aggregation

Tags: c#, performance, architecture, scheduled-tasks, scalability

I'm trying to workout a simple architecture for a tool I'm prototyping. The Web-based tool (.NET based) will basically request data from multiple public APIs, collate and process the response data (JSON or XML) and save the aggregated data in the database. It sounds straight-forward, but the tool needs to run this process (of request/processing/storage) at-least once a day, every day, for about 3000 users. Running the process periodically as a scheduled task (cron job) will dramatically deteriorate the performance and escalate resource usage on the server (single VPS).

So the question is, what sort of an architecture or framework can be utilized to make such a tool fast and scalable, yet simple and easily implementable.

Any ideas and thoughts are appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing issues with resource consumption peaking during the times when the cron run, then instead of a cron run your program continuously. The details of breaking the program so that it can run continuously depends on details. e.g. lets say you have 3000 users; one simplistic approach would be to process one user every 28 seconds.

Fast - you did not mention what exactly is slow in your program, what algorithms you have used etc. Your question sounded like you are running into problems of peaky load. Many a times the fast programs cause peak resource usage. To me it sounds like you will do well to make your program (deliberately) slow. AND Slow does not mean that you design your program inefficiently.

Scalability - If we assume that your base algorithms are good, one way to make is scalable is to add more machines!!